# Install and use git with Ruby

Tags: git, rubygems

I've been using putty to install ruby gems on my vps with some success.  I've successfully installed and configured sass, compass etc, but seem to be having trouble installing and using git.

I've installed the gem with

```
gem install git
```

and this works fine, according to the output, but I don't seem to be able to do anything with it from that point.  For example

```
git -v
```

tells me

```
-jailshell: git: command not found
```

Any ideas?  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I'm no rubyist, but the [git gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/git) seems to be a library for manipulating git with Ruby, not a full installation of git. If you want to run stand-alone git commands, you need to [install git itself](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux you will have to install git through your package manager:

e.g.: `sudo apt-get install git` (on ubuntu etc)

It's not a ruby library so it won't work by trying to `gem install git`. Please go to http://git-scm.com for more information how to install it on your particular server.